# Time values are not making sense on an excel graph

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have an excel graph as shown below:

[image]

As shown in the Draw Down table on the left hand side, the time values are actual time values. However, the graph is treating it as just numbers. So, for example, 8.6,8.8 the Time on the x-axis does not makes sense. Is there a way I can mention the time values just like its mentioned in the draw down table on the left hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using code:

```
Sub TimeintoChartAxes()
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "h:mm;@"   'time value containing column
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "h:mm;@"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Solution without code:

**a**.Select time axis column > Change the number format to TIME or customized time as per requirement.

**b**.Select time axis in chart > Right click > format axis > number > time > change type or format code > close.

**Appended part : for above option a** :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Changing it to TIME format changes it to different time. Also, Where should I mention the code in the excel sheet?

Comment: Home > Number > More Number Formats > Type (as per your need) > ok

Comment: This is what I am doing. I am selecting the "A" column on the excel sheet, then after right clicking, I go to Format Cells option, there after selecting Number, as you mentioned, I don't see "More Number Formats" option. Are you referring to something else which I have misunderstood?Please clarify.